# How do I block domains using the hosts file on Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, dns, hosts-file, nslookup

I used to block domains on Windows using the hosts file like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 www.cnn.com
```

However, now it is not working and the domains are resolving.

```
$ nslookup www.cnn.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  cdns01.comcast.net
Address:  2001:558:feed::1

Name:    turner-tls.map.fastly.net
Addresses:  2a04:4e42:1c::323
          151.101.117.67
Aliases:  www.cnn.com

>ping www.cnn.com

Pinging turner-tls.map.fastly.net [2a04:4e42:1c::323] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2a04:4e42:1c::323: time=16ms
```

I don't know what changed. How can I continue to block domains using the `hosts` file on Windows? Why did Windows suddenly stop using the `hosts` file?

```
>icacls \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                                    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
                                    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Users\Chloe>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

C:\Users\Chloe>nslookup www.cnn.com
Server:  cdns01.comcast.net
Address:  2001:558:feed::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    turner-tls.map.fastly.net
Addresses:  2a04:4e42:1c::323
          151.101.117.67
Aliases:  www.cnn.com
```

Windows 8.1

Comment: `nslookup` doesn't use the `hosts` file. See [domain name system - Nslookup not using hosts file - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/698058/nslookup-not-using-hosts-file/698060) and [windows - What can cause a DNS lookup to ignore a hosts file entry? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/95036/what-can-cause-a-dns-lookup-to-ignore-a-hosts-file-entry)

Comment: Use `ping` to test your host file entries.

Comment: Please do not call people rude when they are trying to help you. It is against the [Code of Conduct](https://superuser.com/conduct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DavidPostill Yes, that was *exactly* it! `ping` is not finding the domains.

https://serverfault.com/a/698060/123651

> nslookup does NOT use hosts file but DNS.
>
> Try using ping instead and it will return the IP provided in your hosts file.

```
$ ping www.cnn.com

Pinging www.cnn.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

It is very strange that the domains were resolved to begin with, as the entries in the `hosts` file have existed for months.